# static and dynamic objects in uiscrollview

Tags: objective-c, uiscrollview, iboutlet

I have some issue. i want to show static and dynamic objects in scrollview. i've IBOutlets and they are connected. I want to change the message and title, they are created manually in code. All others objects are static. My code is here:

.h file:

```
@interface MessageContentViewController (){
    IBOutlet UIImageView  *avatarImageView;
    IBOutlet UIScrollView *scrollView;
    IBOutlet UIImageView  *msgBoardImg;
    IBOutlet UIImageView  *topBarImg;
    IBOutlet UIButton     *backBtn;
    NSMutableArray *allMessages;
}

@property int indexOfMsg;

@end
```

.m file:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"background.jpg"]]];

    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];
    [scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(scrollView.frame.size.width * allMessages.count, 0)];
    [scrollView setPagingEnabled:YES];

    [scrollView scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake(scrollView.frame.size.width * indexOfMsg, scrollView.frame.origin.y, scrollView.frame.size.width, scrollView.frame.size.height) animated:NO];
    for (int i = 0; i < allMessages.count; i++) {

        UIView *tempSubView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.view.frame.size.width * i, self.view.frame.origin.y, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
        [tempSubView addSubview:topBarImg];
        [tempSubView addSubview:backBtn];
        [tempSubView addSubview:msgBoardImg];
        [tempSubView addSubview:avatarImageView];
        [scrollView addSubview:tempSubView];
    }

    [scrollView setContentOffset: CGPointMake(scrollView.frame.size.width * indexOfMsg, 0)];

    CGRect currentViewFrame = CGRectMake(scrollView.frame.size.width * indexOfMsg, scrollView.frame.origin.y, scrollView.frame.size.width, scrollView.frame.size.height);
    [scrollView scrollRectToVisible:currentViewFrame animated:NO];

}
```

.xib file:

[image]

Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You should implement scrollview's delegate method `scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:`, in which you can detect scroll distance then set different title and message for different scroll view.